# Error with France character

Tags: mongodb, zend-framework

I can not insert into mongodb by using zend framwork when I input data like this " Prénom ". See message error below.

**Message:**
An error occurred
Application error
Exception information:
Message: non-utf8 string: Pré

Comment: `utf8_encode()` since PHP is by default cp

Comment: Already use this function, but still not work.